# What is the best way to implement user login system for website with hapi.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, hapi.js

What is the best way to implement user login system for website in hapi.js framework ?

I have searched a lot through the internet but I still don't know which module I should use to implement such authentication. I prefer using passport but the documentation for passport and hapi is so brief. Can anyone suggest me any module? Or a detailed documentation for passport and hapi.js ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do basic authentication, take a look at [hapi-auth-basic](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic). Alternately, you may wish to look at [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie).

If you're looking for third-party login via oAuth there is [Bell](https://github.com/hapijs/bell).

For more on authentication with Hapi take a look at [the tutorial on hapijs.com](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth).